# ROOT 6.06 Installation

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install the [ROOT](https://root.cern.ch/) 6.06 framework on Ubuntu, and have chosen the "environment driven" build method as per the README. I have two problems:

1. I am unsure of which argument to pass to ./configure when I run it. I am currently trying `./configure linux` because `uname` returns "Linux". However, there are a variety of other linux options amongst which I am having a hard time distinguishing.
2. When I run `./configure linux`, it fails while checking for c++11 mode. I tried `apt-get install c++11` and it completed successfully, but the configuration still fails in the same place.

   ```
   Checking whether compiler can generate dependencies ... no  
   Checking whether c++11 mode is supported ... no  
   configure: c++11 mode is requested but the current compiler does not support it.
   ```

Any help in determining whether one or both of these hangups is the core issue is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Install `build-essential`: `sudo apt-get install build-essential`.

Comment: Running Ubuntu 15.10 and I did run it with `c++` rather than `g++`.  It looks like g++ is already up to date. I ran `apt-get install build-essential` and it was up to date as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced a similar problem compiling ROOT when I used `./configure linux --enable-python` on 64bit Ubuntu 15.10. Solved it by typing `./configure linuxx8664gcc --enable-python`.